# Implementing function - spy

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Currently I am working on "spy" for other function. Idea is rather simple: I just replacing invocation of original function with that original function plus incrementing of counter.

Problem is that my counter is visible only in inner scope. How can I expose it to a object property?

```
function Spy(target, method){
  this.count = 0;

  var counter = 0;

  target[method] = (function() {

    return function() {
      ++ counter;   
      this.count = counter;
      console.log(counter);
      return target[method];      
    };    
  })();
}

var spy = new Spy(console, 'error');

console.error('error1'); // prints 1, but not 'error1'
console.error('error2'); // prints 2, but not 'error2'
console.error('error3'); // prints 3, but not 'error3'

console.log(spy.count); // prints 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
function Spy(target, method){
  this.count = 0;

  var self = this,
      oldmethod = target[method];

  target[method] = function() {
    self.count++;
    console.log(self.count);
    return oldmethod.apply(target, arguments);      
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function Spy(target, method){
  this.count = 0;

  var counter = 0;

  target[method] = (function(self) {

    return function() {
      ++ counter;   
      self.count = counter;
      console.log(counter);
      return target[method];      
    };    
  })(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will work:

```
function Spy(target, method){
  this.count = 0;

  var counter = 0;
  var self = this;

  target[method] = (function() {

    return function() {
      ++counter;   
      self.count = counter;
      console.log(counter);
      return target[method];      
    };    
  })();
}
```

You were trying to access `this` scope of inner function that you were returning